# Validator ValidatorFactory is missing

Tags: hibernate, jboss, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to migrate an ejb project to jboss eap 6.2 so from hibernate3 to hibernate4
When i deploy the project on the new jboss. I'm getting

`"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJB_project.SharedUsersWS.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJB_project.SharedUsersWS]",`

that error i get for each session bean, not the entity beans.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using Bean Validation (or Hibernate Validator) in the project you are trying to migrate?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem, it had nothing todo with the validator, during the deployment i had another validation unrelated exception that occurred. Which caused the bean services to not start. Which caused the error about missing/unavailable dependencies..

the reference to the validatorFactory is misleading. It should be read as: this bean service is missing or unavailable (in this case not started because of the exception during deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem with the same exceptions which are confusing.
In my case, I used JBoss, java EE, CXF and SOAP. The problem was in discrepancies in the annotations which were generated by CXF and in my service (@WebService).
The error was looked like

```
"{
\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.subunit.\\\"com.something.MyService.ear\\\".\\\"MyService-web.jar\\\".POST_MODULE\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\\\"com.something.MyService.ear\\\".\\\"MyService-web.jar\\\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \\\"MyService-web.jar\\\" of deployment \\\"com.something.MyService.ear\\\"
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy\"},
\"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [
    \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\\\"com.something.MyService\\\".MyService-service.MyServiceBean.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\\\"com.something.MyService-ear\\\".MyService-service.MyServiceBean]\",
    \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\\\"com.something.MyService\\\".MyService-service.MyServiceBean.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\\\"com.something.MyService-ear\\\".MyService-service.MyServiceBean]\"
]
}"
```

There were no other errors in the log so I used debug on `sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` and that how I found my issues.

Hopefully, it will help.